# Applications misbehaving on Kubuntu 14.04 fresh install

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, kubuntu, crash

I'm having the hardest time trying to install Kubuntu 14.04, alongside Windows XP, on my ASRock Z68 Pro3-M motherboard along with an Intel Core i7 2600K processor and 8Gb of memory. I've also tried Linux Mint, and Xubuntu to no avail.

On each of the installation steps, it takes forever to get to the next step. Once installed, most applications like Audacity and Chrome keep crashing. Utilities like Bleachbit and Synaptic fail to load if I've already run a few programs or had a crash. Previous versions like 12.04 and 13.04 installed just fine with no crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Before jumping to conclusion I'll suggest you to run **Memtest** on your machine, let it go to at least Tests 8, ideally let it run up to Tests 16 and above to make sure your RAM sticks are not defective.

Since you tried several distros already, it's unlikely you had a bad download for all of them.

So, based on your description, it sounds like a problem with defective RAM sticks in your machine.

Memtest is usually included, and installed by default with most of any Linux distros you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Earlier versions install just fine, even now, and my guess is that 14.04 is not liking either the bios settings or some hardware. I can see where your going with the RAM test and I'll check that, but it's odd that only 14.04 trips up--unless it's a specific area of RAM that is affected.

Comment: Memtest checks out OK. I had also tried installing 14.04 without installing updates and propriety software. I'm wondering if there are any assumptions in the install routines that is conflicting with the XP requirements related to the BIOS setup.

Comment: Have you tried setting the BIOS back to factory default?It still seems odd that the machine works fine with WinXP, but it does not like any of the Linux distros.
If this a newer machine, perhaps the BIOS is set to UEFI, if so, try to set it to Legacy mode.
Another thing you can do is try and go over your sudo gedit /var/log/syslog
then look for any failed or error reported in there.

Comment: Only Ubuntu 14.04 and its desktop variants exhibit a problem, not with earlier versions like 12.04, or 13.10 Setting the BIOS to UEFI mode might be challenging to get a dual boot with XP, but first I should take a look at the syslog (thanks) and see if I can find a drive to insert into my StarTech trayless hot swap mobile rack if I don't see anything. I won't be able to do this for a week or so though.

Comment: I've not been able to respond until now for personal reasons, but I did take a look at the syslog for 12.04 as audacity and fontforge are regularly crashing. The only thing I can see that's obvious is:

Comment: backlighthelper: QDBusConnection: system D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave. Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!  dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers. (note: only the dnsmasq-base is installed)